# Windows 10 Hardware 'Shift' key is disabling Chinese IME

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, language

Added chinese(simplified) keyboard layout in windows 10, and by default after reboot chinese keyboard layout will enabled for all applications. Internally, chinese keyboard has Key combination `CTRL+Shift` to switch between english and chinese (Pinyin).

The problem here is the key `Shift` from Hardware keyboard also works as language switch from chinese.

i.e. it disables the chinese IME

Please help, how to stop this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While in the Chinese Input Method, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> will switch between
Chinese mode and English mode, which is undesirable for some people.

This behavior can be changed in Windows 10 as follows:

- Open *Settings > Time & Language > Language*
- Under Preferred languages, select your Chinese flavor
- Once expanded, click *Options*
- Under Keyboards, select your input method (ChangJie / Quick / PinYin / etc.)
- (Here is where I'm running blind:) You should have a Mode Change Key or
  Mode Switching or similar. Change "Shift" to "None".

Here is a screenshot I located on the Internet, as I'm not using Chinese:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was annoyed by this as well, i think microsoft or someone has fixed it. I found the option in the Microsoft Pinyin, Keys section. Images here for reference:

[image: Microsoft Pinyin screenshot]

[image: Keys screenshot]